# Description based on each checkbox "checked" to populate into a summary on the 2nd tab (sheet)

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, formulas, google-sheets-query

I am building a spreadsheet that has to tab (sheets), the 1st I have an "assessment checklist" with about 250-30 checkboxes based on what is found. Example (Checkbox is in "A" column and description is in "B" column). I would like the description based on each checkbox "checked" to populate into a summary on the 2nd tab (sheet).

Is this something that can be accomplished at all, and is this something that can be done using a running report with a date?

For instance (Date 1/1/11 and summary in column "A of sheet two", Date 1/18/11 and summary in column "B of sheet two"... etc.

Comment: pls share a copy of your sheet

Comment: Welcome. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score -1):

```
=QUERY(Sheet1!A:B, "select B where A=TRUE", 0)
```

[image: 0]

Comment: This is one of many alternatives. Please add a brief explanation to explain how this work specially because QUERY isn't a common spreadsheet function.